# How to find the first instance in the same column with condition with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have a data of stock prices like that

```
     ticker       date      close      volume    type  target_date
0     NVDA    1999-01-22    1.6086    18469934  STOCK          
1     NVDA    1999-01-25    1.6270     3477722  STOCK          
2     NVDA    1999-01-26    1.6822     2342848  STOCK          
3     NVDA    1999-01-27    1.5439     1678315  STOCK          
4     NVDA    1999-01-28    1.5349     1554613  STOCK
```

I need to add to 'target_date' column value equal the first date when close price more or equal close * 3. I want to find the first date when close price becomes three times more.
I tried that:

```
df['target_date'] = df[df.close >= df.close * 3].drop_duplicates('ticker')['date']
```

But got NaT values in the whole column

Upd.1
I write that

```
target_date = []
for i in df.itertuples():
    close = i.close
    date = i.date
    f1 = df.date > date
    f2 = df.close > close
    f = f1&f2
    result = df[f].drop_duplicates('ticker')['date']
    target_date.append(result.iloc[0])
```

and got "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds"

UPD2
I think I did it

```
target_date = []
for i in df.itertuples():
    close = i.close
    date = i.date
    f1 = df.date > date
    f2 = df.close > close
    f = f1&f2
    result = df[f].drop_duplicates('ticker')['date']
    try:
        target_date.append(result.iloc[0])
    except:
        target_date.append(pd.NaT)
df['target_date'] = target_date
```

But is it the way to make it more elegant?

Comment: Please provide us the sample data. close column is missing in your data. This `df.close >= df.close * 3` doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Do `df[:5].to_dict()` and add the data to the question, the data you have in the question currently is missing the column used by the expression you have written

Comment: There is Close column in the data actually. But I fixed code for more clarity

Comment: `df.close >= df.close * 3` only happens if `df.close == 0` ;) There seems to be a problem in your question

Comment: I need to change df.close * 3 with something that would be equal three times of the testing close value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `df` dataframe contains your data and a `target_date` column, this code should do the trick:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    rest = df.iloc[i+1:]  # the rest of the rows (next ones)
    x = rest[rest.close >= 3*row.close]
    df.loc[i, 'target_date'] = np.nan if len(x) == 0 else x.iloc[0].date
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
5622 rows was done in 30 s. Now I think how to speed up the calculating